# Disable Calculation of Modifiers

Tags: modifiers, objects, boolean-modifier

I created a complex scene. I put a lot of *Boolean* modifiers (without Apply) on various objects. Now the file won't open and hangs. Is there any **Safe Mode** in Blender? For example, a ban on the calculation of *modifiers* when loading a file.
Blender version 3.6.2.

Comment: Try opening a new file and then seeing if you can use File > Append to load your objects from the file that Blender won't open directly. You may be able to just add some of the meshes without the boolean objects (assuming you've named them appropriately so that you can tell which are which!), or load them in batches and disable some of the modifiers before loading more.

Comment: Blender does not have "*Safe Mode*".

Comment: No it doesn't have Safe mode which is why I suggested trying to append your objects a few at a time into a new file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the backup file *.blend1. It had fewer objects with the *Boolean* modifier. And everything was restored. Safety in Blender is provided by backup files.

Comment: You were lucky in that case!

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot!